# Elasticsearch 5.1.1 Keyword/Text datatype takes twice the size as the String datatype

Tags: elasticsearch

When I updated an ES 2.4.1 index to ES 5.1.1 I notice that the size of the index became much bigger. So I did an experiment to create an index with one text field document and add one million of this document to the index.

In ES 2.4.1 the index size became around 45.0 MB (not analyzed `String` datatype) and in ES 5.1.1 it became around 93.6 MB (the `Keyword` datatype).

I've tried to find anything about this in the documentation and so on but with no luck so far. Any explanation/solution to this?

Comment: Can you share the mapping you used for 2.4 and 5.1?

Comment: Could be also different default char/token analyzer configuration in new version.

Comment: Of course, for 2.4: `"mappings": {
"stringnotanalyzedtest": {
"properties": {
"stringField": {
"index": "not_analyzed",
"type": "string"
}
}
}` and for 5.1 '

Comment: For 5.1 `"mappings": {
      "keywordtest": {
        "properties": {
          "keywordField": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }`